# How to convert a string of an array into an actual array in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I can't seem to find an inbuilt function to convert a string of an array e.g. `"[0 1 2 3]"` into an actual array in Clojure i.e. `[0 1 2 3]` that I can use to access elements from (e.g. `(get [0 1 2 3] 1)`).

Any advice?

Edit: Actually, my data is "[Class]:[1 803 584 839 617]", for which the `read-string` function seems to return `[Class]` - any idea why? I can work around this by splitting by ':' first but I was wondering if there's a direct way to use it on the given string.

Comment: That worked for my example. Actually, my data is `"[Class]:[1 803 584 839 617]"`, for which the read-string seems to return `[Class]` only - any idea why? I can work around this by splitting by ':' first but I was wondering if there's a direct way to use it on the given string.

Comment: `read-string` reads one object from the string only. In your case, that object is a vector which contains one symbol `Class`.

Comment: How do I get it to iterate through the entire vector to get the remaining of the string?

Comment: Your complete string isn't made up of valid objects, but the portion after the `:` is a single valid object. Your workaround to split the string is the way to go. If a string was a valid concat of objects, then you can use `read` to read each object:
`(defn read-string-all [s]
  (with-open [reader (-> s .getBytes io/reader java.io.PushbackReader.)]
    (doall (take-while #(not= :the-end %) (repeatedly #(read {:eof :the-end} reader))))))`

Comment: Ok got it, thanks!